# Java rest calls with get parameters

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3

How do you add parameters or extra line code to rest calls in java.

```
GET /ObjectName HTTP/1.1  
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com  
Date: date Authorization: authorization string (see Authenticating Requests (AWS  Signature Version 
4)) Range:bytes=byte_range
```

Putting `/Objectname` after `GET` on the  set method causes an error.

The code i am using is;

```
public void getObject() throws Exception   {
  String fmt = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ";
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt, Locale.US);
  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  String ob2 = "/bucket/test.txt";
  String bucket = "/bucket";
  String method = "GET"; 
  String contentMD5 = "";
  String contentType = "";
  String date = df.format(new Date()) + "GMT";        

  // Generate signature
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
  buf.append(method).append("\n");`enter code here`
  buf.append(contentMD5).append("\n");
  buf.append(contentType).append("\n");
  buf.append(date).append("\n");
  buf.append(ob2);   
  String signature = sign(buf.toString());

  HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
  URL url = new URL("https”,”s3demo.s3demosite.com",443,bucket);
  httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  httpConn.setDoInput(true);
  httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
  httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
  httpConn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
  httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
  httpConn.setRequestMethod(method);
  httpConn.setRequestProperty("Date", date);
  httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
  String AWSAuth = "AWS " + keyId + ":" + signature;
  httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", AWSAuth);

 // Send the HTTP PUT request.
 int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
 InputStream err = httpConn.getErrorStream();
 InputStream is = null;
 is = httpConn.getInputStream();
 int ch;
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while ((ch = err.read()) != -1) {
  sb.append((char) ch);
 }
 if ((statusCode/100) != 2)
 {
    // Deal with S3 error stream.
    InputStream in = httpConn.getErrorStream();
    System.out.println("Error: "+errorStr);
 }
 else {
    System.out.println("download worked”);
 }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code you're using so far?

Comment: are you want to pass a parameter to rest services ?

Answer (score 0):

In REST Services you can pass a parameter in two ways.

1. as path variables
2. As a query argument. Example: `GET /students/tom` or `GET /students?name=tom`

Comment: Yes. Just I explain we have two ways to pass parameter to REST services.

Comment: If you see the added code the line httpConn.setRequestMethod(method); It will only accept GET POST etc. And adding path variables will cause a program error.

Comment: yes.it will give error.in the GET request parameters are sent as a part of URL.

Comment: why we can't use POST with HttpURLConnection.first we open the connection.then after we can write parameters to the connection. Is it possible thing?

Comment: Sorry I am new to rest. Are you saying that I could do a post and do a GET to download the file?